# Trigger an action when new permission is inserted

Tags: django

I defined my custom permission through Meta Class

```
class Meta:
permissions = (
        ("my_permission", "My Permission"),
   )
```

How can I trigger an action when a new permission is inserted?

E.g., if I add a new permission called my_permission_2, I want to call an API.

Can I do it overriding save method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by overiride the save method. But way of going ahead would be to use Django Signals. Using them is quite easy.

For example,

```
#When you try to add a new permission to a model
user.permissions.add(<new_permission>)

#This callback function would be invoked based on what event you want to fire it
@receiver(post_add, <Model_name>)
def callback(*args, **kwargs):

...
```

There are variety of events available. Take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/)

Comment: You mean you don't really want to award permission to an User but declare a permission on a model dynamically?

Comment: Yes, i want  to trigger the action when I declare a permission on a model dynamically!

Comment: I see, can you post how and where you are adding the permission dynamically

Comment: i will add permission just entering a new codeline in class meta, manually :)

Comment: I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve doing this. If you are manually going to update the permissions then, too use them you would have to sync the database with out which it won't make any sense.